# Xamarin Essentials Google login Auoth , send me AuthToken work for just one hour

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-signin, xamarin.essentials

I try to get AuthToken for google for xamarin form app my back end is Asp.net API, everything ok I got the AccessToken but work for just one hour and then I need to login into a Google account again,? my respect for any help
I'm using this example

https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/main/Samples/Sample.Server.WebAuthenticator

Comment: So just reauthenticate once the token expires..

Comment: do you have a link to how to reauthenticate this token, please?

Comment: @haydarM.Al-samawe You can try to use **Xamarin.Auth** to refresh AuthToken, firstly override the GetInitialUrlAsync method to request a refresh token, then create a method to request our refresh token. More detailed info, you can google **Xamarin.Auth and refresh tokens**

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT thanks for your reply I'm using  Xamarin Essentials as a link in my question, so this is must be Xamarin stander for several external login methods, I know there are several ways to make this login, but I'm looking for something that will be with Xamarin Essentials,

Comment: @haydarM.Al-samawe About refresh AuthToken, you can take a look :[Google API Oauth2 Refresh token bad request 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68337297/google-api-oauth2-refresh-token-bad-request-400)